# Should I mention react-native as a dependency for my react-native library?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

I'm creating a react-native library that needs some of react-native modules in order to work.
Should I mention react-native as a dependency for my project in package.json dependencies?

I saw some other react-native npm packages which mentioned react-native as devDependencies. why they do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's required for the app to work, you should specify it as a dependency in your package.json.

If it's required, but the user will always have react-native available (e.g. if your library is being used as part of a larger react-native project) you can set it in peerDependencies. This means your app needs it to work, but it doesn't automatically bundle react-native with your code.